# Split Pandas DataFrame objects into 2 JSON objects

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a requirement to send JSON data via API Rest call, but the files need to be separate as there is a file size limit.

I currently collect the data from a HANA database, and split it into 2 files:

```
connection = dbapi.connect(address='<>',port='<>',user='<>',password='<>')
df = pd.read_sql('''QUERY''', connection)

length_df = len(df)
length_half = math.ceil(len(df) / 2)

if length_df > length_half:
    payload_1 = df[:length_half]
    payload_2 = df[length_half:]
```

This returns 2 perfectly separated DF's, that I need to process as JSON objects.

After this has been done, I iterate over these DF's separately, and put them into the required format that the client wants it as:

```
item_data_load_1 = {}
for row in payload_1.itertuples(index=False):
    list = {
        "itemId": {
            "primaryId": row[0].lstrip('0')
        },
        "description": {
            "languageCode": "",
            "descriptionType": "",
            "value": row[25]
        },
        "classifications": {
            "itemType": row[7]
        },
        "tradeItemBaseUnitOfMeasure": row[8],
        "demandUnitInformation": {
            "demandUnitName": row[0].lstrip('0'),
            "description": {
                "value": row[25]
            },
            "actionCode": "",
            "demandUnitDetails": {
                "demandUnitBaseUnitOfMeasure": row[8],
                "brandName": row[6],
                "unitSize": row[19],
                "handlingInstruction": {
                    "handlingInstructionCode": ""
                }
            }
        }
item_data_load_1.append(list)


item_data_load_2 = {}
for row in payload_2.itertuples(index=False):
    list = {
        "itemId": {
            "primaryId": row[0].lstrip('0')
        },
        "description": {
            "languageCode": "",
            "descriptionType": "",
            "value": row[25]
        },
        "classifications": {
            "itemType": row[7]
        },
        "tradeItemBaseUnitOfMeasure": row[8],
        "demandUnitInformation": {
            "demandUnitName": row[0].lstrip('0'),
            "description": {
                "value": row[25]
            },
            "actionCode": "",
            "demandUnitDetails": {
                "demandUnitBaseUnitOfMeasure": row[8],
                "brandName": row[6],
                "unitSize": row[19],
                "handlingInstruction": {
                    "handlingInstructionCode": ""
                }
            }
        }
item_data_load_2.append(list)
```

I do this for both payloads, and then dump it into a JSON object:

```
json_data_1 = json.dumps(item_data_load_1)
json_data_2 = json.dumps(item_data_load_2)
```

However, the first file I produce has the correct amount of records in it, but the second file has double that - it's like it's taking the data from the first payload, and then also appending the other half of the second payload (essentially making it one big file).

```
Row count of 1st dataframe:
44938
Row count of 2nd dataframe:
44938
Row count of full dataframe:
89876
Length of 1st payload:
39139770
Length of 2nd payload:
78279080
```

This should not occur, though, as it should just produce 2 JSON files with the same record counts.

I cannot share the full script as it has sensitive information in it.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the complete code that produces the issue- the example snippets only show parts of it.

Comment: After you've fetched the data to Python, it doesn't depend on the backend DB: be it HANA, Oracle, SQL Server or even Ingres. So I remove HANA tag.

Comment: What about the question itself: if you do not do anything with your data that really requires it to be "dataframed", you may use a plain [`cursor.fetchmany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchmany) and do batching in natural way without predefined number of variables to hold that data

Comment: @astentx, so I use numpy and pandas to do some processing on the data that is irrelevant to the issue. 
Below is the output
Row count of 1st dataframe:
44938
Row count of 2nd dataframe:
44938
Row count of full dataframe:
89876
Length of First payload:
39139770
Length of First payload:
78279080